# Maven Resource Error with Fast-MD5

Tags: maven

I'm a Maven newb so this is probably simple.  Relative sections of POM are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fast-md5</groupId>
    <artifactId>fast-md5</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

and:

```
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
   </repository>
```

Now when I check the path and drill down it looks like everything should match up.  However, I get this error:

```
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository central (http://central)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.snapshot (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/snapshot)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository central (http://central)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.snapshot (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/snapshot)
Downloading: http://nmtg-maven:9081/nexus/content/groups/nmtg-ems-group//fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'fast-md5:fast-md5:pom:2.5' in repository jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.
```

What did I do wrong and what in "nmtg"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what this `nmtg-maven` machine is (very likely some internal stuff that you should actually not see). Anyway, I don't know why you need the pom but I couldn't reproduce the problem, the artifact gets successfully downloaded:

```
8/23/10 5:45:29 PM CEST: Downloaded https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/fast-md5/fast-md5/2.5/fast-md5-2.5.pom
```

This must have been a temporarily problem.

Comment: I just reproduced and got the same error.  Did you use my text as is?  If so I can try slimming down my pom...in fact I'll do that to test right now.

Comment: @nick Yes I did use your snippet as is.

Comment: Tried trimming the POM way down so that other things wouldn't get in the way and I get the same error.  Confusing.  I can always fall back on adding it to the local repository but I hate doing that.

Comment: @nick Are you behind a proxy? A firewall? I just can't reproduce :-s